# EAOutputStream write:maxLength: - 230 failed to write because stream does not have space available

Tags: iphone, ios, external-accessory

I was using this. It was working well till I upgraded my iphone to IOS 6.1.

```
[[session_ipos outputStream] write:ui8Buff maxLength:tot];
```

Now its giving an error message:

> ERROR -
>   /SourceCache/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-213/EAOutputStream.m:-[EAOutputStream
>   write:maxLength:] - 230 failed to write because stream does not have
>   space available

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with the help of Demo from

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html

I changed the way i was trying to access External Accessories and related functions.

Comment: It could help a lot explaining what were you doing and what you did to solve the error

Answer (score 1):

try to write in UI Thread

```
EASession _session

InvokeOnMainThread (() => { 
   _session.OutputStream.Write(byteArray);
});
```

Comment: This is the answer.